# Node JS, logging JSON with ansi code

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm simply trying to log JSON with some ANSI styling codes, in Node.js, here is the code, with several examples:

```
let s = chalk.green('Hello World')
let o = {s} // or {s: s}

console.log(s)
console.log(o)
console.log(o.s)
console.log(JSON.stringify(o))
```

*(Note: `chalk` is just like `colors`)*

But the formatting is escaped when logging an object or stringifying it. Is there any way to prevent it?
Result:
[image]

So it's just like logging `\u001b[32mHello World\u001b[39m` and `\\u001b[32mHello World\\u001b[39m` (with double `\`)

PS: I know there are hundred of workarounds but I stumbled on that problem and I've been looking for a simple solution. Thx!

Comment: What is the end result you want to achieve?

Comment: Having colors when logging the object. Or not escaping the style codes when using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: so you would want `{"s": "Hello World"}` where Hello World is green?

Comment: Exactly! (Of course the goal is not to concatenate the key and the value together, I'm mainly asking because of curiosity, I don't really understand why there is the behaviour with stringify and I'ld like to know if it can be done differently.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a (kind of dirty) fix:

```
JSON.stringify(o)
  .replace(/\\/g, '')
  .replace(/u001b/g, '\u001b')
```

So if the string contains `\u001b`, `stringify` will escape it: `\\u001b`. By replacing `/\\/g` it actually matches with only `\` but it seems to also the one added by `stringify`.
The second `replace` will re-add, only one and unesaped `\`.That's the best I got so far.

Answer (score 0):

To strip the ansi escape codes from each of the string values in an a object, try this:

```js
const stripAnsi = require("strip-ansi")
const mapObj = require("map-obj")

const stripAnsiObj = (object) => mapObj(object, (key, value) => [key, stripAnsi(value)])
```

Usage example:

```js
const chalk = require("chalk")

const object = {a: chalk.green("Hello World")}

JSON.stringify(object)
//=> {a: "\u001b[32mHello World\u001b[39m"}

JSON.stringify(stripAnsiObj(object))
//=> {a: "Hello World"}
```