# Allow for control chars with util.inspect / console.log

Tags: node.js

I have this callback with an error:

```
return cb({code, message: `Could not run the following command: "${chalk.bold(cmd)}".`}, result);
```

it gets handled like so:

```
if (err) {
   console.error(err);
   process.exit(1);
 }
```

I get this (notice the control chars):

```
{ code: 1,
  message:
   'Could not run the following command: "\u001b[1mnpm view @oresoftware/foo2@latest dist --json\u001b[22m".' }
```

I also tried handling like this instead:

```
if (err) {
   console.error(util.inspect(err));
   process.exit(1);
 }
```

and

```
if (err) {
   console.error(chalk.magenta(util.inspect(err)));
   process.exit(1);
 }
```

but I always seem to get the control chars - is there some way to configure `util.inspect()` to accept control chars?

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

**Here is a very simple repro:**

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
const util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect({message: `Here is the highlighted message ${chalk.bold('foo bar baz')}`}));
```

Comment: note that `util.inspect(x, {colors:true})` does not solve the problem. using colors:true actually does what console.log() does by default in the newer nodejs versions.

Answer (score 1):

[`util.inspect` escapes control characters](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.8.0/lib/util.js#L123), this cannot be changed.

Escape sequences can be unescaped, as mentioned in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585390/how-to-unescape-utf-8-characters-in-node-u00f6), for instance:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(`"${util.inspect(obj).split('"').join('\\"')}"`))
```

Or any existing third-party package that does same thing can be used, e.g. `unescape-js`.

Answer (score 0):

I thought maybe the JSON.stringify is adding a escape() to the control characters. And it was it, upon researching I kinda created a solution but found out it was posted in another SO post:  [Node JS, logging JSON with ansi code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733987/node-js-logging-json-with-ansi-code)

Where the OP @Cohars proposed (which is same as mine)

> ```
> JSON.stringify(o)
>   .replace(/\\/g, '')
>   .replace(/u001b/g, '\u001b')
> ```

Now, in case of `util.inspect` I think same solution should work:

```
util.inspect(obj)
  .replace(/\\/g, '')
  .replace(/u001b/g, '\u001b')
```

Note: I didn't understand if we should flag the question as duplicate or not. But as you asked a completely different thing I thought maybe this question should be treated as another.